# Why I received an Error 403 with MockMvc and JUnit?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, junit, spring-security, mocking

I have a spring mvc (3.2.5) application with spring security (3.2).

I configured my SecurityConfig.class with this method :

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/*").permitAll().and()
            .formLogin().successHandler(successHandler)
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
            .failureHandler(failureHandler).failureUrl("/login?error=true")
            .permitAll().and().logout()
            .permitAll();

    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll();

    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/welcome").permitAll();

    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/secure/*").authenticated();
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN").anyRequest().authenticated();
}
```

With Spring security (3.2) I have CSRF enabled. I think it is a good idea to let it enabled.

My controller SignInController contains 2 methods with params :

*EDIT* : adding `action=` in params

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/signup")
    public ModelAndView signup() {

        boolean auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null ? false
                : SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()
                        .isAuthenticated()
                        && (SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                                .getAuthentication().getPrincipal() instanceof User);

        ModelAndView result = null;

        if (auth) {
            result = new ModelAndView("redirect:" + "/");
        } else {
            UserForm user = new UserForm();
            result = new ModelAndView("registration", "userForm", user);
        }
        return result;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/register", params = "action=signup")
    public ModelAndView registration(
            @ModelAttribute(value = "userForm") @Valid UserForm userForm,
            BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request) {

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return new ModelAndView("registration");
        }

        Member member = profileFacade.registerNewUser(userForm);

        return new ModelAndView("registration", "member", member);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/register", params = "action=cancel")
    public ModelAndView cancelRegistration() {
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:" + "/");
    }
```

and finally, I have JUnit test :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @WebAppConfiguration
    @ContextConfiguration(classes = { WebConfiguration.class,
        JpaConfiguration.class, LoggingConfiguration.class,
        SecurityConfig.class, DataSourceEmbeddedConfiguration.class,
        DataSourceMySqlConfig.class, BaseValidatorConfiguration.class })
    @TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager", defaultRollback = true)
    @ActiveProfiles("dev")
    public class SignInControllerTest {

        @Autowired
        private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;
        @Autowired
        private MockHttpSession session;
        @Autowired
        private MockHttpServletRequest request;
        @Autowired
        private FilterChainProxy springSecurityFilterChain;

        private MockMvc mockMvc;

        @Before
        public void setUp() throws ServletException {

            SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter scharf = new SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter();
            scharf.afterPropertiesSet();

            this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                    .webAppContextSetup(this.webApplicationContext)
                    .addFilters(springSecurityFilterChain).dispatchOptions(true).build();

            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);
        }
        @Test
        public void signup() throws Exception {
            mockMvc.perform(get("/signup")).andExpect(status().isOk())
                    .andExpect(model().attributeExists("userForm"));
        }

        @Test
        @Transactional
        @Rollback(true)
        public void register() throws Exception {

            UserForm form = new UserForm();
            form.setEmail("email@email.com");
            form.setUsername("aokije");
            form.setPassword("klo,ksff");
            form.setConfirmedPassword("klo,ksff");

            mockMvc.perform(post("/register").param("action", "signup")).andExpect(status().isOk());
        }

    }
```

*EDIT* : update mockMvc.perform because it is working fine with `http.csrf().disable()` in SecurityConfig.class

Test ***signup*** run perfectly but ***register*** return an error 403.
I tried a lot of things but I received always this error.

When I try `http://localhost:8080/register?signup` in a browser, it is working fine.

_*EDIT*_

Logs :

```
2014-02-13 22:00:14,695 [ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource] processMap Adding web access control expression 'permitAll', for org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.PermitAllSupport$ExactUrlRequestMatcher@52ee705c 
2014-02-13 22:00:14,696 [ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource] processMap Adding web access control expression 'permitAll', for org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.PermitAllSupport$ExactUrlRequestMatcher@2412d28d 
2014-02-13 22:00:14,697 [ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource] processMap Adding web access control expression 'permitAll', for org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.PermitAllSupport$ExactUrlRequestMatcher@4fbd397b 
2014-02-13 22:00:14,697 [ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource] processMap Adding web access control expression 'permitAll', for Ant [pattern='/logout'] 
2014-02-13 22:00:14,698 [ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource] processMap Adding web access control expression 'permitAll', for org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.PermitAllSupport$ExactUrlRequestMatcher@1008e323 
2014-02-13 22:00:14,699 [ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource] processMap Adding web access control expression 'permitAll', for Ant [pattern='/*'] 
2014-02-13 22:00:14,700 [ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource] processMap Adding web access control expression 'permitAll', for Ant [pattern='/resources/**'] 
2014-02-13 22:00:14,700 [ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource] processMap Adding web access control expression 'permitAll', for Ant [pattern='/welcome'] 
2014-02-13 22:00:14,700 [ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource] processMap Adding web access control expression 'authenticated', for Ant [pattern='/secure/*'] 
2014-02-13 22:00:14,701 [ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource] processMap Adding web access control expression 'hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')', for Ant [pattern='/admin/**'] 
2014-02-13 22:00:14,701 [ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource] processMap Adding web access control expression 'authenticated', for org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1 
2014-02-13 22:00:14,703 [FilterSecurityInterceptor] afterPropertiesSet Validated configuration attributes 
2014-02-13 22:00:14,704 [FilterSecurityInterceptor] afterPropertiesSet Validated configuration attributes 
2014-02-13 22:00:14,734 [DefaultSecurityFilterChain] <init> Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@10174779, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@68736a7e, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@728e5d0d, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@6e7a918b, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@430e85e7, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@55eda087, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@290c7ca, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@6dd90afc, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@12eb6a0f, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@6855612f, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@410a11a2, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@59e15580, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@2257a0] 
2014-02-13 22:00:14,859 [FilterChainProxy] doFilter /register at position 1 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter' 
2014-02-13 22:00:14,863 [FilterChainProxy] doFilter /register at position 2 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter' 
2014-02-13 22:00:14,863 [HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository] readSecurityContextFromSession HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT 
2014-02-13 22:00:14,863 [HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository] loadContext No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpSession@4c4b529f. A new one will be created. 
2014-02-13 22:00:14,864 [FilterChainProxy] doFilter /register at position 3 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter' 
2014-02-13 22:00:14,865 [HstsHeaderWriter] writeHeaders Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@5ab39e58 
2014-02-13 22:00:14,865 [FilterChainProxy] doFilter /register at position 4 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter' 
2014-02-13 22:00:14,866 [CsrfFilter] doFilterInternal Invalid CSRF token found for http://localhost/register 
2014-02-13 22:00:14,866 [HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository] saveContext SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession. 
2014-02-13 22:00:14,866 [SecurityContextPersistenceFilter] doFilter SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Could you help me ?

Thanks a lot

***EDIT***

Finally, I had a bug in another class (annotation). I fix with this :

```
HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository httpSessionCsrfTokenRepository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
        CsrfToken csrfToken = httpSessionCsrfTokenRepository
                .generateToken(request);

        Map map = new HashMap();
        map.put("userForm", form);
        map.put("org.springframework.security.web.csrf.HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository.CSRF_TOKEN",
                csrfToken);
        this.mockMvc
                .perform(
                        post("/register")
                                .param("signup", "")
                                .param("_csrf", csrfToken.getToken())
                                .sessionAttrs(map)).andExpect(status().isOk());
```

Params csrf and sessionAttrs are mandatory.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Post requests need the CSRF token to be added to the form. So you have to pass it while testing:

```java
var TOKEN_ATTR_NAME = "org.springframework.security.web.csrf.HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository.CSRF_TOKEN";
var httpSessionCsrfTokenRepository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
var csrfToken = httpSessionCsrfTokenRepository.generateToken(new MockHttpServletRequest());

mockMvc.perform(
  post("/your/path/here")
    .sessionAttr(TOKEN_ATTR_NAME, csrfToken)
    .param(csrfToken.getParameterName(), csrfToken.getToken())
    ...
);
```

Second thing, are you sure that the registration method handles your post request? Isn't RequestMapping configured for "GET" by default?

Comment: Thanks but it is not working. 
I tried this : It is not working. I tried this : 
`mockMvc.perform(post("/register").param("action", "signup").session(session).sessionAttr("_csrf", csrfToken)).andExpect(
    status().isOk());
`
I received same error. 

If I disable csrf with http.csrf().disable() in my SecurityConfig, it is working fine (without .sessionAttr())

Comment: try to use
"org.springframework.security.web.csrf.HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository.CSRF_TOKEN";

instead "_csrf", forgot to post that ;  )

Comment: I don't have access to constant CSRF_TOKEN. It doesn't exist in the class. All other constants are private.

Comment: its only string, key for attribute in session. Just pass it as first parameter:
.sessionAttr("org.springframework.security.web.csrf.HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository.CSRF_TOKEN‌​", csrfToken)

Comment: The problem persist. I had test with HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository.class.getName().concat(".CSRF_TOKEN") but it failed too. If I check csrfToken, paramvalue is "_csrf".

Comment: sorry, I should reread whole class before answer. Add also .param with csrf itself
".param(csrfToken.getParameterName(), csrfToken.getToken())"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47413/discussion-between-freakman-and-jonathan-lebrun)

Answer (score 90):

I know this question is quite old, but this is one of the first results on Google for some queries and I believe this approach is much better and it is [described on spring.io blog](https://spring.io/blog/2014/05/23/preview-spring-security-test-web-security)

1) You can create your `mockMvc` with Spring Security support easier, so your `setUp()` gets much shorter:

```java
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
            .webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
            .apply(springSecurity())
            .build();
}
```

2) You can use `org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.request.SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.csrf()` to populate your test request with correct CSRF token like this:

```
mockMvc.perform(post("/register")
              .with(csrf())
              .param("action", "signup"))
     .andExpect(status().isOk());
```

Comment: Awesome, just saved me. It is required when you have `http.csrf().disable()` in security config.

Comment: @AnilBhaskar Why do you have to use it when you specify csrf is disabled?

Comment: If you are looking for an answer in spring-boot2, you can check my answer which solve both issues regarding with http 403 and http 401 problems. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54839518/1577363

Comment: This answer worked for me and is way simpler than the accepted answer.

Comment: Nice and simple.
You can also setup MockMvc with `@Autowired MockMvc mvc` and use [@WithMockUser](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/test.html#test-method-withmockuser) on your Test Method.

Answer (score 28):

Try with `@AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false)`

Comment: Don't know why it works, but it works and fixes my unit tests. Thanks...

Comment: worked for me too! Can you explain why?

Comment: Usually, you have a SecurityFilterChain that configures the HttpSecurity with parameters like http.csrft()....addFilter(...) etc.. This code disables the security filter for unit test.

Answer (score 1):

For reactive apps using `org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.WebTestClient`, try `.mutateWith(csrf())`, as in

```
import org.springframework.security.test.web.reactive.server.SecurityMockServerConfigurers.csrf

@Autowired private lateinit var webTestClient: WebTestClient

@Test fun `the endpoint works`() {
  webTestClient.mutateWith(csrf()).get().uri("/ui/home")...
}
```

Source: [Spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/test/web/csrf.html)